# how to show only catergory titles on a page in wordpress

Tags: wp-query

How do you show category titles on a page in wordpress. I want to to show the category titles on my home page which would then link to the first post in that category. I also want to show the image of the first post in that category.

Any way i can do this? i was thinking wp_query?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You will need to combine [`get_categories()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_categories) and [`wp_query`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query)

First you should get all categories and loop through each one of them. Inside the loop you need a `wp_query` to get the title and the image of the latest post per category. At last you should reset the post data.

Place the code below inside your homepage template:

```
$args = array (
    'hide_empty' => 1,
);
$terms = get_categories( $args );

foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
    $query = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'post', 'cat' => $term->term_id, 'posts_per_page' => 1 ) );

    if ( $query->have_posts() ) {
        while ( $query->have_posts() ) { 
            $query->the_post();
            $postlink = get_the_permalink( $query->ID );
            $postimage = wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id( $query->ID ) );
            echo '<h4><img src="'.$postimage.'"><a href="'.$postlink.'">'.$term->name.'</a></h4>';
    }
} 

// Restore original Post Data
wp_reset_postdata();
}
```

Comment: @PieterGoosen May I know what is the reason for the downvote?

Comment: Glad I could help @Raj